# Kentico File URL for file uploaded with a custom page type

Tags: kentico

I've created a new page type with a file upload field and a name field. In my transformation i can't get the URL of the file. I'm reading through the v9 docs but GetFileURL brings me to the adHoc page that's created, not the uploaded file.

Here's my transformation so far (the FeaturedType is from a drop down selection):

```html
Title: <%# Eval("FeatureTitle") %>
File: <%# Eval("FeatureFile") %>
<li><span class="<%# Eval("FeatureType") %>"></span><a href="<%# GetMediaFileUrl(Eval("FeatureFile")) %>" target="_blank"><%# Eval("FeatureTitle") %></a></li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have Field with: Data type: File, and Form control Upload file oraz Direct uploader you can use this method, without the Eval wrap.

```
<%# GetFileUrl("FeatureFile") %>
```

FeatureFile contains only GUID of the attachment.

If you have Field with data type text and form control as media selection you can use just

```
 <%# Eval("FeatureFile") %>
```

because it contains the path to the file.

Comment: Thanks Neshi. I went back to the built in cms.file page type ans saw that was set to direct upload. All is working, now for some SASS love. Cheers!

Comment: @dawid   Thank you for the answer, it really helped :)